# ClickHouse: How to store JSON data the right way?

Tags: sql, clickhouse, yandex, yandex-metrika

I'm going to migrate data from PostgreSQL database to Yandex's ClickHouse.
One of the fields in a source table is of type JSON - called `additional_data`. So, PostgreSQL allows me **to access json attributes** during e.g. `SELECT ...` queries with `->>` and `->` and so on.

I need the same behavior **to persist** in my resulting table in ClickHouse storage. (i.e. the ability to parse JSON during select queries and/or when using filtering and aggregation clauses)

Here is what I've done during `CREATE TABLE ...` in ClickHouse client:

```
create table if not exists analytics.events
(
    uuid UUID,
    ...,
    created_at DateTime,
    updated_at DateTime,
    additional_data Nested (
        message Nullable(String),
        eventValue Nullable(String),
        rating Nullable(String),
        focalLength Nullable(Float64)
        )
)
engine = MergeTree

ORDER BY (uuid, created_at)
PRIMARY KEY uuid;
```

Is that a good choice how to store JSON-serializable data? Any Ideas?

Maybe It's better to store a JSON data as a plain `String` instead of `Nested` and playing with It using [special functions](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/)?

Comment: Does the structure of json-document is fixed and won't be changed?

Comment: @vladimir It can be altered with some new properties in future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Although ClickHouse uses the fast JSON libraries (such as [simdjson](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson) and [rapidjson](https://rapidjson.org/)) to parsing I think the Nesting-fields should be faster.
2. If the JSON structure is fixed or be changed predictably try to consider the way of denormalizing data:

```sql
..
    created_at DateTime,
    updated_at DateTime,
    additional_data_message Nullable(String),
    additional_data_eventValue Nullable(String),
    additional_data_rating Nullable(String),
    additional_data_focalLength Nullable(Float64)
..
```

On one hand, it can significantly increase the count of rows and disk space, on another side, it should give a significant increase in performance (especially in the right indexing). Moreover, the disk size can be reduced using [LowCardinality-type](https://altinity.com/blog/2020/5/20/reducing-clickhouse-storage-cost-with-the-low-cardinality-type-lessons-from-an-instana-engineer) and [Codecs](https://altinity.com/blog/2019/7/new-encodings-to-improve-clickhouse).

3. Some others remarks:

- avoid to use Nullable types, prefer to use some replacement such as '', 0, etc (see explanation [Clickhouse string field disk usage: null vs empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63058842/303298))
- UUID type doesn't give [index monotonicity](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#use-of-index-for-partially-monotonic-primary-keys), this one should be much better ([More secrets of ClickHouse Query Performance](https://youtu.be/1TGGCIr6dMY?t=466)):

```sql
..
ORDER BY (created_at, uuid);
```

- consider using [Aggregating-engines](https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-continues-to-crush-time-series) to significantly increase the speed of calculation aggregated values

4. In any case before making a final decision need to do manual testing on a data subset (this applies as to choose the schema (json as string/Nested type/denormalized way), as choosing the column codec).

Answer (score 3):

As of 22.3, there is a `JSON` data type https://clickhouse.com/blog/clickhouse-newsletter-april-2022-json-json-json/

Comment: Although this does require the `allow_experimental_object_type` to be SET. Can be done by `SET allow_experimental_object_type = 1;`